# How would I associate users with different company tables?

Tags: postgresql

In the below diagram you can see I have profiles for users. A user means the profile is associated with a login. If they don't have a login account they are merely a "contact" at the company tables you see on the right.

I am creating a CRM that needs to be able to store many facilities, customers, vendors, etc.

My question is how would I associate that profile with the company it belongs too? If I went to there profile page, for example, I should see what company they work for, regardless of what table the company is in.

[image]

I have 2 ideas but both seem flawed. One is to make a separate profile table for contacts for each. Example. `vendor_profiles`, `customer_profiles`, etc. This seems messy.

My other idea was to make a `vendor_id`, `customer_id`, etc column in the profile table, set them all to `NULL` by default, and if they belong to a vendor then my application code would check each for a number, and I think you get where I am going from there. Again, seems very messy, and inefficient.

I also considered grouping the Vendors, Customers, so on into one table and just setting a "type" but they all store very different info and are used in different, and often, relational ways.

Comment: Hi Matt, off-topic question, what software did you use to generate that visual representation of tables?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly; the vendor is the company you're trying to link to, right?

Comment: Dbdesigner.net which I highly reccomend.

Comment: I want to link a profile with any of the 4 other tables, but only one. A profile is a person who works at either a vendor, a customer, our company, or facility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a new `organization` table which unifies those aspects of `vendor`, `customer`,
`facility` and `our_company` that they all share in common:

```
CREATE TABLE organization (
    organization_id serial4
    type text);

CREATE TABLE profile (
    profile_id serial4
    user_id int4 REFERENCES user
    organization_id int4 REFERENCES organization
    ...);
```

Then add an `organization_id` foreign key to `vendor`, `customer`, `facility` and `our_company`
so these tables can be joined to `organization` when the extra info in those tables are needed.

```
CREATE TABLE vendor (
    vendor_id serial4
    organization_id int4 REFERENCES organization
    vendor_specific_field text
    ...);
```

---

Note that if you use "unique" names for id fields (such as `organization_id` instead of `id`) which have a consistent meaning across all tables, then you can `JOIN ... USING` syntax

```
SELECT *
FROM profile p
INNER JOIN organization o USING (organization_id)
INNER JOIN vendor v USING (organization_id)
WHERE o.type = 'vendor'
```

instead of

```
SELECT *
FROM profile p
INNER JOIN organization o ON p.organization_id = o.id
INNER JOIN vendor v ON v.organization_id = o.id
WHERE o.type = 'vendor'
```

which may improve readability and reduce potential errors in join conditions. (You'll never have to wonder what field in one table connects to the `id` field in another table.)

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I just couldn't wrap my head around this

Comment: 2 Questions. Shouldn't my foreign key "organization_id serial4 REFERENCES organization" be int4? or is serial4 correct? I thought serial4 auto-increments?